# Linux script which will display XML encoding

Tags: xml, linux, bash, encoding

I need to write Linux script which will display XML encoding attribute.

E.g. for file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
    <foo/>
</example>
```

I want to get text `UTF-8`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you wanting to scan arbitrary attributes, or just very specifically the `encoding` attribute for the `?xml` tag?

Comment: Using a XML parser or via pure shell scripting?

Comment: I'm interested only in <code>encoding</code> attribute from <code>?xml</code>

Comment: I need pure shell scripting solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -oP "encoding=[\"']([^\"']+)" $file | head -1 | cut -c 11-
```

*To make it case insensitive, one has to add the `-i` switch to `grep`.*

it takes into account the usage of `'`, and inputs like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a b="" />` when there is no new line.

Comment: +1 for the point about not necessarily having a newline, although a fairly redundant use of `cat`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have this habit of `cat`ing content then processing it. I edited the answer to get rid of it.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use `-i` (XML is case sensitive). 2. XML allows new lines between attributes. Rare but it happens :-) 3. You should really limit that to the first line - you'll get odd bugs when the XML contains elements or text `encoding="..."`. 4. You should print `UTF-8` if you can't find an XML header (default value).

Comment: Fixed 1. and 3., still has to deal with 2, 4, and 5: When there is no encoding attribute in the html header, but in other places. e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" ?><a encoding="blablabla" />`

Answer (score 0):

Could use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) or `BASH_REMATCH`, e.g. `BASH_REMATCH` version

```
read -r line < file && [[ $line =~ [E|e][N|n][C|c][O|o][D|d][I|i][N|n][G|g]=\"([^\"]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Alternatively could use `shopt -s nocasematch` to ignore case for simpler bash regex.

Comment: Is it case insenstive? Will it work if someone writes ENCODing="UTF8"?

Comment: @PawełAdamski See update. Not sure if there is a simpler syntax with basic bash regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU sed 4.2.1`:

```
sed -n -e '/<?xml/{s/\(<?xml[^>]*encoding=.\)\([^'"'"'\"]*\)\(.*\)/\2/p;q0}' $f
```

Explanation:

- `-n` : avoid printing until ordered by program
- `/<?xml/` : match line containing preamble
- `s/` : start string substitution
- `\(<?xml[^>]*encoding=.\)` : match preamble up to the opening quote as group `\1`
- `\([^'"'"'\"]*\)` : match everything except for `"` or `'` as group `\2`
  (escaping needed for `bash` and `tcsh`)
- `\(.*\)` : match rest of line as group `\3`
- `/\2/p;q0` : replace matched parts with group \2, print it and quit

Test:

```
1: printf '\n<?xml ?><someElement encoding="someEncoding"/>\n' | sed -n -e '/<?xml/{s/\(<?xml[^>]*encoding=.\)\([^'"'"'\"]*\)\(.*\)/\2/p;q0}'  
 > no output
2: printf '\n<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?><someElement encoding="someEncoding"/>\n' | sed -n -e '/<?xml/{s/\(<?xml[^>]*encoding=.\)\([^'"'"'\"]*\)\(.*\)/\2/p;q0}'
 > UTF-8
```

I am actually use this to replace the written encoding with a desired one (iso-8859-1):

```
sed -e '/<?xml/{s/\(<?xml[^>]*encoding=.\)\([^'"'"'\"]*\)\(.*\)/\1ISO-8859-1\3/}' utf8.xml > iso8859-1.xml
```